# Регулярное выражение для извлечения кодировки из meta-тега (Delphi, TRegExpr)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, delphi, utf-8

День добрый!

Как правильно составить регулярное выражение, чтобы получить из следующих строк кодировку UTF-8?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" charset=UTF-8" />
```

Используется Delphi > TRegExpr.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама регулярка:

```
charset=("|)(.{1,9})"
```

Тебе нужно отлавливать 2-ю группу. В регулярке используется то, что в конце всегда кавычки и они одни. 
Тестировать регулярки можно тут http://regexr.com/

---

PS. моя регулярка не строгая, в некоторых случаях будет работать неправильно, например если закрывающих кавычек будет 2 или не будет вовсе.

Comment: Спасибо! Если не сложно, подскажите ещё выражение для получения таких значений из метатегов, как KEYWORDS или DESCRIPTION, для случая, когда все метатеги склеены в одну строку, например:
 
    <meta name="KEYWORDS" content="фото объектов с мягкой черепицей, страница 2, Москва, Shinglas" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta><meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="В данном разделе сайта компании представлены фото объектов с мягкой черепицей Shinglas, страница 2." /></meta>

Comment: более-менее универсальная регулярка:
DESCRIPTION.{3,29}"([^"]{1,500})"

Эта регулярка ищет ключевое слово, потом пропускает несколько символов, ищет открывающую кавычку, потом смотрит все символы до следующей кавычки. Тебе нужна первая группа.
Ключи для регулярки: Ignore case, Multiline, Singleline.

Comment: последний вопрос, как собрать содержимое тегов <h2>...</h2>, если их на странице несколько?

Comment: если внутри тегов нет лишних '<', то примерно так:
<h2>([^<]{1,1500})</h2>

(эта регулярка будет игнорировать заголовки с вложенными тегами)

Кусочек программки:
RegEx := TRegEx.Create(EditFind.Text, Options);

if RegEx.IsMatch(MemoSrc.Text) then
begin
 M := RegEx.Matches(MemoSrc.Text, EditFind.Text, Options);
 {// получаем коллекцию совпадений}
 for i := 0 to M.Count - 1 do
 begin
   MemoTarg.Lines.Add(M.Item[i].Value); {// выводим совпадение}
   for j := 0 to M.Item[i].Groups.Count - 1 do
    MemoTarg.Lines.Add('   Группа ' + IntToStr(j) + ' ' +M.Item[i].Groups[j].Value)
 end;
end;

Comment: ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

`charset="?(.*)"` группа №1 будет содержать искомое значение.

[Regexper](http://regexper.com/#charset%3D%22%3F%28.*%29%22) Вам в помощь.